# How to Run Ansible Playbook using a public ssh key

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to run my Ansible playbook on a remote server using a provided ssh key.

I have added the following configuration to my inventory file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    server1:
      ansible_host: sample.server@noname.com
      dest_dir: /root
      sample_tree: sample_tree.txt
      private_key_file: ../config/id_rsa_tf
```

I have referenced it in my playbook using the following:

```
- name: "Nightly Deploy"
  hosts: server1
  remote_user: sysuser
  tasks:
    - name: Copy test from local to remote
      tags:
        - copy
        - all
      copy:
        src: "test.tgz"
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}/test.tgz"
```

I am running the playbook with the following command:

`ansible-playbook --tags="copy" -v -i inventories/nightly-build.yaml  playbooks/nightly-build.yaml`

The error I'm getting is the following:

> fatal: [server1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to
>   connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-  keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}

Is my `private_key_file` wrong in my inventory file or am I calling it wrong? and help would be great

Comment: might be a user issue as well. Are you passing the correct user, you can try passing it using -u.

Comment: Do I have to pass the user at run time, if I am specifying a remote_user in the playbook?

Comment: See https://ansibledaily.com/troubleshooting-ansible-connection-issues/

Comment: Both comments really helped thanks.
turns out, my issue was caused by not passing the host and passing the wrong var name in my inventory, it should be `ansible_ssh_private_key_file`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This error usually occurs when there is no valid public and private key generated and setup.

Try any of the following approaches:

1. Create/edit your ansible.cfg file in your playbook directory and add a line for the full path of your key:

   ```
   [defaults]
   privatekeyfile = /Users/username/.ssh/private_key
   ```

   It sets private key globally for all hosts in your playbook.
2. Add the private key to your playbook using the following line:

   ```
   vars:
     ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa"
   ```
3. You can also define the private key to use directly in command line:

   ```
   ansible-playbook -vvvv --private-key=/Users/you/.ssh/your_key playbookname.yml
   ```

Comment: in the `[defaults]` section `privatekeyfile` should be change to `private_key_file`